# How to check "From Email" via WordPress before an email is sent

Tags: php, email

Is it possible to check an email from email via WordPress before an email is sent?

I'm working on a phpmailer plugin to send WordPress email via Amazon SES (which requires all emails to be verified). I'm using WordPress multisite and would like to set a different verified email per site.

So I would like to know if it is possible to get the variable that contains the from email to accomplish something similar to the following.

```
if(fromEmailVaribale == 'info@example.com'){
 //Set from email
  $phpmailer->SetFrom('info@example.com', 'Example.com');
}else{
 //Set from email
  $phpmailer->SetFrom('services@example.com', 'Services Example.com');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In [`wp_mail()`](http://queryposts.com/function/wp_mail/) there are filters to adjust from address:

```
// Plugin authors can override the potentially troublesome default
$phpmailer->From     = apply_filters( 'wp_mail_from'     , $from_email );
$phpmailer->FromName = apply_filters( 'wp_mail_from_name', $from_name  );
```

However they don't seem convenient for your needs because they don't provide access to mailer object at the same time.

You are probably better of using action hook further down

```
do_action_ref_array( 'phpmailer_init', array( &$phpmailer ) );
```

to check what `$From` field in it holds and adjust if necessary.

Comment: Thanks for responding I'm not too familiar on how to use the do_action_ref_array can you please explain it a bit further thanks

Comment: @Oudin do you know how to work with action hooks in general? It's just slightly different form of `do_action()`, so use `add_action()` and get mailer object passed as argument to your callback.